# jsPDF How to set images to fit with various page size height & width to a single PDF file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jspdf

I have multiple types of data images of different sizes (height & width) that need to be converted to PDF using jspdf,html2canvas but I have trouble when I download pdf its works for small name user data but when I get a big name or other data then in right side it's got increase and go out of the page like distorted it's working if the user name is small and less data but when data get its go out of the page from X side I tried **scrollX: 0** and **scrollX: -window.scrollX** both but not getting in proper see the image below the data number getting out and how can I improve PDF quality . ?

```
export const pdfDownloadHandler = (name, div, user) => {
  const input = document.getElementById(div);
  var clientHeight = input.clientHeight;
  var clientWidth = input.clientWidth;

  html2canvas(input,{
    scrollX: 0,
    scrollY: 0,
  }).then((canvas) => {
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'px', [clientWidth, clientHeight]);
    console.log('@PDF: ', pdf, user);
    var width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
    var height = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

    function loadImage(url) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let img = new Image();
        img.onload = () => resolve(img);
        img.src = url;
      })
    }


    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'jpeg', 0, 0, width, height);
    pdf.text(`Reviewed By Analyst : ${user} on ${new Date().toLocaleString()}`, 450, 35);
    pdf.setFontSize(16);
    pdf.text("Powered By ", width - 500, height - 20)
    loadImage(solytics).then((logo1) => {
      pdf.addImage(logo1, "png", width - 425, height - 35, 90, 25);

    });

    loadImage(banklogo).then((logo) => {
      pdf.addImage(logo, "png", 15, 0, 85, 55);

      pdf.save(`${name}.pdf`);

    });


  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this is possible but a bit tricky, you can substract the Y coordinate by `user` length. For the example if I set the font size to 12:

```
const user="ihsan fajar ramadhan"
doc.setFontSize(12);
doc.text(`Reviewed By Analyst : ${user} on ${new Date().toLocaleString()}`, 105 - user.length*2.1, 25);
```

the Y coordinate of the text will follow the `user` length so it will not go out of the page. but the equation is not perfect in that example, I suggest you to make a graph (with excel or something) and generate the trendline to get the most desirable equation.